# Fetch thrown and swallowed Exception from CurrencyManager

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, data-binding, currencymanager

The .NET Windows Forms `CurrencyManager` swallows exceptions that are thrown while navigating (see ["Bug in CurrencyManager.OnPositionChanged - eats exceptions" on MSDN Social](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/5dd4f0f1-2197-450d-b2ac-79f18d437a88/)).

I, however, need to catch or fetch an exception that may be thrown in a `CurrentChanged` event handler. Is there a way to get it? Subscribing `BindingComplete` and reading `e.Exception` does not help.

```
bindingSource.MoveLast();
// exception isn't thrown up to here

private void bindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // save old, throws exception
}
```

At the moment, the user gets no feedback when saving the old item fails. Therefore I need a way to get the exception.

Cheers
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to fetch it through: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException`

Simple example code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception thrown: {0}", e.Exception.GetType()));

            try
            {
                ThrowException();
            }
            catch(InvalidProgramException)
            {
                // mjam mjam
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void ThrowException()
        {
            throw new InvalidProgramException("broken");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the job. I wrapped the exception in a `WrappedException` class, to differentiate between the exception I want and others thrown in the domain (`is` operator).